# how to get the title of the listview in androidstudio

Tags: java, android, listview

I was writing a code to get the contacts in the phone with the below code 
`StoreContacts.add(name + "\n"+ phonenumber)`

How do I get only the name from the list.

```
private void showContacts() {
    c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

    contacts = new ArrayList();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        String contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME ));
        String phNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        contacts.add(contactName + "\n" + phNumber);

    }
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd like to help, but I don't understand your question. What is `StoreContacts`? Why do you need to get the name when you already have it in `contactName`? What does your question have to do with `ListView`? There is no reference to `ListView` in any of the code you shared. For additional help, please [edit] your question to include the details. Also check out [mcve] for some tips on creating a good code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.split() method to split string by given strings

```
for(int i=0;i<contacts.size();i++){
        String strings[] = contacts.get(i).toString().split("\\n");
        String name= strings[0];
        Log.i("name",name);
}
```

Comment: @AnilKumar as it has solved the problem, you should accept the answer :)